# Laravel storing a db field to a file

Tags: laravel, database, file

I have to save a db field to a text file so that later it can be converted to PDF and mailed out.

I wrote a small test function:

```
function summonstoFile($id)
{
    $path = public_path('files/summons');
    if (!File::isDirectory($path))
        {File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);}
    $su = Summons::find($id);
    $fl = asset($path)."/".$su->id;
    Storage::put($fl, $su->summons);
}
```

Simply, check the path exists and make it if it does (that works fine) open the database at the correct record and then store the details in the appropriate field ($su->summons) as a text file called {{$su->id}}.txt.

It writes nothing.

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `asset` function helper returns URL. For saving file you need file path. Try with `Storage::put($path . '/' . $su->id . '.txt', $su->summons);`.

Comment: I tried that and still nothing in the directory.

Comment: Incidentally the use is:

```use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use File as FL;
use App\Models\Summons;'''

Comment: `FL !== File` (if used in code that way). Solved now? Do you get any error in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file?

Comment: Not quite certain what you mean about FL !== file. the file is lower case. THE FL is only there because PHP demands an alias. There is nothing in the log at all.

Comment: If you have imported class and aliased it as `use File as FL;`, than in code you should use it similarly to `if (!FL::isDirectory($path)){/** */}`. PHP demands it if you have another class that's base name is File, otherwise you don't need to alias it. Also, instead File, import facade like `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;` or `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File as FL`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use Storage::put, the file will be put in the default disk. By default, the default disk is local with storage/app path.

You can try:

```
 $su = Summons::find($id);
 Storage::put('files/summons/' . $su->id , $su->summons);
```

Then go to storage/app/files/summons to check it

Comment: Tried. Directory still empty. 
I have removed making the directory so use has only 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Models\Summons;

Comment: Can you show your new code? It should be a relative path like my code, not an absolute path

Comment: ` $path = public_path('files/summons');
    $su = Summons::find($id);
    $fl = asset($path)."/".$su->id;
    Storage::put('files/summons', $su->summons);`

Comment: I have amended the code to:

` $path = public_path('files/summons');
    $su = Summons::find($id);
    $fl = $path."/".$su->id;
    Storage::put($fl, $su->summons);`

Comment: I edited my answer,  try  Storage::put('files/summons/' . $su->id , $su->summons);

Comment: This is getting very weird. It has put the but very deep under storage - about 6 directories down. I just wanted it to be in the public directory!

Comment: It's not weird. As i said in my answer, the file will put in storage/app. As my code, it will be put in  storage/app/files/summons folder

Comment: Its actually put it in storage/app/home/masonic/lodge/public/files/summons

Comment: Yeah, because you don't use my code. You use your code.

Comment: With your code, it will put it in 'storage/app/' . public_path('files/summons'). Why don't you try dd( public_path('files/summons'))

Comment: I've solved it by making a disk in config/filesystem called pdf which is in public then saving it with `Storage::disk('pdf')->put($su->id.".txt", $su->summons);`